# Testing for the presence or absence of an attribute

Tags: protractor, cucumber, bdd, gherkin

I'm not sure it can be done, but is it possible write an assert/expect to pass where the presence or absence of something, e.g., an HTML element attribute, passes? Or am I stuck with failing one or the other version?

I'm writing a test for an `anchor` element. The test expectation is the link will open in the same window.

```
<a href="https://foo.com">Foo</a>
```

Now, as any web developer will know, the above example will do just that. **However**, a second version of this link is also possible:

```
<a href="https://foo.com" target="_self">Foo</a>
```

The use of `target` is a matter of style and most certainly superfluous in any case. I have pages where the presence or absence of `target="_self"` seems arbitrary.

Any suggestions or examples?

**NB** I'm considering using this as opportunity to fail one or the other and using it as an opportunity to correct the HTML in an "enhancement." Which may answer the question a different way.

Comment: Hope I'm understanding your question.  It's not possible to have a conditional assert, but you use conditionals to create a path to a specific assertion.  Can you just call `getAttribute('target').then(function(val) { if(val)....assertion1... else ...assertion2... })` on the element?  If you need a more complete example, I can write one up.

Answer (score 0):

Hope below code will fulfill your requirement. You may need to change anchor element locator.

```
    element(by.xpath('.//*[text()="Foo"]')) 
      .getAttribute('target')
      .then(function(value){
           //this function gets executed only if target attribute is present
           },
           function(error){
             //this is a error case and will gets executed when target 
             //attribute is NOT present in the anchor element
           }
    );
```